# find substring ignoring whitespaces

Tags: java, string, search

I want to search java strings ignoring whitespaces. for eg

```
abc    cdf   sdf
abc cdf   sdf
abc        cdf     sdf
```

what should be a possible search keyword , may be regular expression.

If I will search the above strings with

```
abc cdf sdf
```

This will not match.

Comment: So, what are you trying to search? Provide an example. And what have you tried so far? Include your code in the question, so that we can tell you where the issue is

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is simple approach to your problem.

Firstly, deleted the whitespaces from string and search using indexOf method.
Hope this approach will help you.

Try with below code:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

    public class IgnoreWhiteSpace {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            String search = "abc    cdf   sdf";

            System.out.println(StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(search));

            System.out.print("Found Index :" );

            System.out.println(search.indexOf( 'c' ));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your solution would match also for example the input String "ab ccdfs df". Which isn't equal to the search pattern "abc def sdf" from the requestor.

Answer (score 1):

Depending other rules this might be a starting point for you.

```
String s = "abc        cdf     sdf";
System.out.println(s.matches("abc\\s*cdf\\s*sdf"));
```

For regex have a look in the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a temporary new string without whitespaces and search in it using the normal way,..